# How to migrate to RouterProvider in the case of paraller Routes?

Tags: react-router-dom

We are trying to migrate RouterProvider to use Data API ([ScrollRestoration](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/scroll-restoration)) in react router dom v6.
It is challenging to handle parallel `Routes` which render two different components under the same path.

I checked and tweaked many examples of single `Routes` and nested `Routes`. None of my tries didn't work.

It is hard to find examples similar to this case. How would you migrate to RouterProvider for the following code? The following is the code I am trying to migrate.

App.tsx

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <TopNav />
      <div className="title">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/support" element={<></>} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Title />} />
          <Route path="/:categoryId" element={<Title />} />
          <Route path="/:categoryId/:subcategoryId" element={<Title />} />
          <Route path="/:categoryId/:subcategoryId/:contentId" element={<Title />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
      <SideNav />
      <div className="content">
        <div className="page-section">
          <main>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/support" element={<Form />} />
              <Route path="/" element={<Content />} />
              <Route path="/:categoryId" element={<Content />} />
              <Route path="/:categoryId/:subcategoryId" element={<Content />} />
              <Route path="/:categoryId/:subcategoryId/:contentId" element={<Content />} />
            </Routes>
          </main>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

index.tsx

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <PrismicProvider client={client}>
     <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
     </BrowserRouter>
    </PrismicProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: You won't be able to use a single Data router and render duplicate routes. Can you [edit] to clarify what specifically you need of the Data APIs? For example, does the title section routes need Data APIs access? What is the use case and/or purpose of these split/duplicated routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to migrate to `RouterProvider` from `BrowserRouter`.
Refactor the code is necessary to remove some repetitions.

I created `RootLayout`, `TitleLayout`, and `ContentLayout`.
Then, I wrapped `Title` component with `TitleLayout`. It goes the same way for the `Content` component.

App.tsx

```js
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter, Outlet, ScrollRestoration } from 'react-router-dom';

import TopNav from './components';
import Hero from './components';
import SideNav from './components';
import Footer from './components';
import ContentPage from './components';
import FormPage from './components';

export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <RootLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/support',
        element: (
          <>
            <TitleLayout>
              <></>
            </TitleLayout>
            <ContentLayout>
              <FormPage />
            </ContentLayout>
          </>
        ),
      },
      {
        path: '/',
        element: (
          <>
            <TitleLayout>
              <Hero />
            </TitleLayout>
            <ContentLayout>
              <ContentPage />
            </ContentLayout>
          </>
        ),
      },
      {
        path: '/:categoryId',
        element: (
          <>
            <TitleLayout>
              <Hero />
            </TitleLayout>
            <ContentLayout>
              <ContentPage />
            </ContentLayout>
          </>
        ),
      },
      {
        path: '/:categoryId/:subcategoryId',
        element: (
          <>
            <TitleLayout>
              <Hero />
            </TitleLayout>
            <ContentLayout>
              <ContentPage />
            </ContentLayout>
          </>
        ),
      },
      {
        path: '/:categoryId/:subcategoryId/:contentId',
        element: (
          <>
            <TitleLayout>
              <Hero />
            </TitleLayout>
            <ContentLayout>
              <ContentPage />
            </ContentLayout>
          </>
        ),
      },
    ],
  },
]);

function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <TopNavigation />
      <Outlet />
      <ScrollRestoration />
    </div>
  );
}

function TitleLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="title">{children}</div>
      <SideNavigation />
    </>
  );
}

function ContentLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="content">
        <div className="page-area">
          <main className="page-content">{children}</main>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

index.tsx

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <PrismicProvider client={client}>
      <App />
    </PrismicProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { CompatRouter } from "react-router-dom-v5-compat";

<CompatRouter>
  <Switch>
   <Routes>
          <Route path="/support" element={<></>} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Title />} />
          <Route path="/:categoryId" element={<Title />} />
          <Route path="/:categoryId/:subcategoryId" element={<Title />} />
          <Route path="/:categoryId/:subcategoryId/:contentId" element={<Title />} />
  </Routes>
 </Switch>
</CompatRouter>
```